# About Javascript object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working on my react native project, and having problem on below function

```
this.notificationListener = FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, async (notif) => {
  console.log(notif.custom_notification);
  console.log(notif.custom_notification.body);
});
```

for the `console.log(notif.custom_notification);` it can log

```
{"show_in_foreground":true,"sound":"default","title":"MyNewApp","body":"ffff","priority":"high"}
```

for the `console.log(notif.custom_notification.body);` it log

```
undefined
```

How can I can the body of the notif.custom_notification?

Comment: Did you try `notif.custom_notification["body"]`?

Comment: parse it first, JSON.parse(notif.custom_notification).body

Comment: @ReiDien Yes, you are right, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to parse it first, otherwise everything in your code looks good. `var i = JSON.parse(notif.custom_notification); i.body`

Comment: I am glad. Thanks for telling. :)